# ifconfig: cannot open /proc/net/dev in Centos 7 container on RHEL7.3

Tags: docker, redhat, rhel, ifconfig, redhat-containers

I'm getting this error while running "ifconfig"  command in my CentOS 7 container

The error i get is

```
cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission Denied)
```

how to solve this..??? I'm getting this problem in my each container. I give full permission to /proc/net/dev but it's not working

Comment: Where is the container running? Which Host OS?

Comment: host os is RHEL 7.3

Comment: So both host and container OS is RHEL 7.3 ?

Comment: no base os is RHEL 7.3  and container os is centos7

Comment: actually i'm working on python cgi ...and i run apache server in it....where i am getting a page on web browser and run "ifconfig " or "ifconfig -a" command on it as a input ..then as out put it's showing this error

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your `docker run ...` command line it is hard to guess but maybe you will like to add `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` to your run command.

From [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities):

```
For interacting with the network stack, instead of using --privileged they should use --cap-add=NET_ADMIN to modify the network interfaces.
```